# Flask don't logging in file

Tags: python, logging, flask

I have same code

```
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
from logging import ERROR, Formatter
from flask.logging import default_handler
database.init_db()
handler = RotatingFileHandler("logs/log.txt", maxBytes=10000, backupCount=10)
handler.setLevel(ERROR)
handler.setFormatter(Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s'))
app.logger.removeHandler(default_handler)
app.logger.addHandler(handler)
app.run()
```

This logging from other modules, using

```
from main import app
try:
    #some code
except Exception as e:
    app.logger.error(e)
```

logs output in console was correct, but they are not written to the file logs/log.txt. What am I doing wrong? File in the 'logs' directory in the project directory with rights 777

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with the help of default dictConfig, like this:

```
from logging.config import dictConfig    

dictConfig({
        'version': 1,
        'formatters': {'default': {
            'format': '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s in %(module)s.%(funcName)s Line %(lineno)s: %(message)s',
        }},
        'handlers': {'file': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': 'logs/admin.log',
            'formatter': 'default'
        }},
        'root': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'handlers': ['file']
        }
    })
```

The dictionary must be defined before creating an instance of the Flask class

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```